# Navigate route in reactjs doesn't work as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-router, navigateurl

I have a route

```
<Route path="/Profile" element={<Profile />} />
```

And when I'm in 'http://localhost:3000/Profile?id=11', the `Profile` component will get the `id` query parameter and render user data respectively. But when I try to navigate to another user using `useNavigate`

```
navigate(`/Profile?id=${userId}`)
```

It just changed the URL ('http://localhost:3000/Profile?id=15') and didn't reload the page and new user data too. So can you tell me why and how to fix it.

Update:
Profile component is like

```
let location = useLocation();
let query = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
const navigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(() => {
  const getUser = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8082/api/getUserInfo', {
      params: {
        id: query.get("id"),
      },
      withCredentials: true,
    })
    setVisitor(res.data.visitor);
    setUser(res.data.user);
  }
  getUser();
}, [])
```

Comment: Did you use an effect watch for the changing id?

Comment: I don't know what the effect watch is.

Comment: Can you show the code inside `Profile`?

Comment: @Zombani: `useEffect`

Comment: There is a lot of code, but it has an useEffect to get user data and just render it.

Comment: Can you show at least how your getting the `id`
 inside `Profile`. And what do you get when call that `navigate`, a blank page?

Comment: It seems odd how you are passing the `id`, since you didn't specify it in your `path`.

Comment: I added profile code, you can check

Comment: Are you by any chance using react router 5.3.0?

Comment: @AdamThomas No, I'm using v6

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The issue is the `useEffect` hook runs only once when the component mounts. The component doesn't remount if the route path doesn't change, it will only rerender when route path parameters or the URL query search changes. The component isn't handling these parameters updating during the life of the component.

## Solution

Use the [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-search-params) hook instead of the `useLocation` hook to read/access the `id` query parameter. Add `id` to the `useEffect` hook's dependency array so the component reruns the `useEffect` callback when the `id` query parameter value changes.

Example:

```
const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
const navigate = useNavigate();

const id = searchParams.get("id");

useEffect(() => {
  const getUser = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8082/api/getUserInfo', {
      params: { id },
      withCredentials: true,
    })
    setVisitor(res.data.visitor);
    setUser(res.data.user);
  }
  getUser();
}, [id]); // <-- pass id as dependency here
```